# Dynamically group by with "Group Header"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could someone help me with this problem. I have a table with Products, ProductsSales. Here are some screenshots of them.

[image: Product table]

[image: Product sales table]

Now I would like to make a TSQL query which can group them and add something like a "header description"?
Something like this

[image: Endproduct]

It would be perfect, if it is a relatively dynamically query.

**Could someone help me here or give me some tipps?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ProductName, B.Price 
FROM Product A 
INNER JOIN Product_Sales B ON A.ProductId = B.ProductId
GROUP BY ProductName, Price
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with  `GROUPING SETS` in SQL Server to get the desired output.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN groupname IS NOT NULL THEN groupname 
         WHEN groupname IS NULL 
              AND productname IS NULL THEN 'food' 
         ELSE productname 
       END          AS GroupName, 
       Sum(s.price) price 
FROM   product p 
       INNER JOIN TableSales s 
               ON p.productid = s.productid 
GROUP  BY grouping sets( ( p.productname ), ( p.groupname ), ( ) )
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/SJAWD22789)

**Output**

```
+------------+-------+
| GroupName  | price |
+------------+-------+
| fruit      | 14    |
+------------+-------+
| vegetables | 52    |
+------------+-------+
| food       | 66    |
+------------+-------+
| Apple      | 5     |
+------------+-------+
| Capsicum   | 35    |
+------------+-------+
| Cucumber   | 17    |
+------------+-------+
| Orange     | 9     |
+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to unpivot the categories and then aggregate:

```
select which, name, sum(price)
from products p cross apply
     (values ('productName', productName),
             ('groupName', groupName),
             ('parentGroup', parentGroup)
     ) v(which, name) left join
     productsales ps
     on ps.productId = p.productId
group by which, name;
```