# Dynamically group by with “Group Header” and Group Footer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

I have a similiar problem like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096980/dynamically-group-by-with-group-header). Supposed we have the same example data as from the linked question. Here the same example data:

Product Table

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| ProductId | ProductName | groupName  | parentGroup |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|         1 | Orange      | fruit      | food        |
|         2 | Apple       | fruit      | food        |
|         3 | Cucumber    | vegetables | food        |
|         4 | Capsicum    | vegetables | food        |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Product Sales

```
+-----------+-------+
| ProductId | price |
+-----------+-------+
|         1 |     5 |
|         1 |     4 |
|         2 |     2 |
|         2 |     3 |
|         2 |     3 |
|         3 |     8 |
|         3 |     6 |
|         4 |     9 |
|         4 |     9 |
|         4 |     7 |
|         4 |    10 |
+-----------+-------+
```

What if I want the total of the group at the bottom. Something like this:

[image]

Is there a way that I can group this data as in the picture and this very dynamically?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Please remove your links to external data, and instead include all relevant data directly in your question.  Links can and do break over time, and you should be prepared to invest a few minutes into formatting your question if you also expect users on this site to do the same trying to help you.

Comment: A *brief* look at those images and I can't see that this'll need to be dynamic. Looks like it just needs some aggregation. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Here's a great resource for [formatting your question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) as needed.

Comment: Hello Larnu, the problem is that this are only example data. I can't publish the real data. I have several "groupNames" in my real data. The question, which is linked above, was really helpful, but I don't have an Idea how i can add a "Groupfooter" as you can see in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly your format is tricky and should probably be done at the application layer.

However, you can use `grouping sets` with my answer to that question to get the totals:

```
select which,
       coalesce(name, groupName + ' Total') as name
       sum(price)
from products p cross apply
     (values ('productName', productName),
             ('groupName', groupName),
             ('parentGroup', parentGroup)
     ) v(which, name) left join
     productsales ps
     on ps.productId = p.productId
group by grouping sets ( (which, name, groupName, parentGroup),
                         (which, groupName, parentGroup)
                       );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. As you may get. I am really new to this stuff. So you suggest, that I should do that in my Web API Application. Are there any specific reasons for that, except the complex SQL Code?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I did this more as a personal challenge but I think it goes to show you how right Gordon is when he states that you should handle this in your application layer.

Techinically, this is possible in pure SQL.  But it is ***a very bad idea***:

```
declare @p table(ProductId int,ProductName varchar(20),groupName varchar(20),parentGroup varchar(20));
insert into @p values
 (1,'Orange','fruit','food')
,(2,'Apple','fruit','food')
,(3,'Cucumber','vegetables','food')
,(4,'Capsicum','vegetables','food');

declare @ps table(ProductId int,price int)
insert into @ps values
 (1,5)
,(1,4)
,(2,2)
,(2,3)
,(2,3)
,(3,8)
,(3,6)
,(4,9)
,(4,9)
,(4,7)
,(4,10);

with p as
(
    select distinct parentGroup
          ,'Start ' + parentGroup as label
    from @p
)
,g as
(
    select distinct groupName
          ,'Start ' + groupName as label
    from @p
)
,ru as
(
    select p.parentGroup
          ,p.groupName
          ,p.ProductName
          ,sum(ps.price) as Sales
    from @p as p
        left join @ps as ps
            on p.ProductId = ps.ProductId
    group by p.parentGroup
            ,p.groupName
            ,p.ProductName
    with rollup
)
,r as
(
    select row_number() over (order by parentGroup
                                      ,groupName
                                      ,ProductName
                              ) as rn
          ,Product
          ,Sales
          ,parentGroup
          ,groupName
          ,ProductName

    from (
        select isnull(isnull(ru.ProductName,g.groupName + ' Total'),ru.parentGroup + ' Total') as Product
              ,ru.Sales
              ,ru.parentGroup
              ,isnull(ru.groupName,'zzzzz') as groupName
              ,isnull(ru.ProductName,'zzzzz') as ProductName
              ,2 as sort
        from ru
            left join p
                on ru.parentGroup = p.parentGroup
            left join g
                on ru.groupName = g.groupName
        where ru.parentGroup is not null

        union all

        select isnull(g.label, p.label) as Product
              ,0 as Sales
              ,isnull(ru.parentGroup,'     ') as parentGroup
              ,isnull(ru.groupName,'     ') as groupName
              ,isnull(ru.ProductName,'     ') as ProductName
              ,1 as sort
        from ru
            left join p
                on ru.parentGroup = p.parentGroup
            left join g
                on ru.groupName = g.groupName
        where ru.ProductName is null
            and ru.parentGroup is not null
        ) as a
)
select Product
      ,Sales
from r
order by rn;
```

## Output

```
+------------------+-------+
|     Product      | Sales |
+------------------+-------+
| Start food       |     0 |
| Start fruit      |     0 |
| Apple            |     8 |
| Orange           |     9 |
| fruit Total      |    17 |
| Start vegetables |     0 |
| Capsicum         |    35 |
| Cucumber         |    14 |
| vegetables Total |    49 |
| food Total       |    66 |
+------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. As you may get. I am really new to this stuff. So you suggest, that I should do that in my Web API Application. Are there any specific reasons for that, except the complex SQL Code? Is this simpler to do this in C#?

Comment: Adding the headers and footers should be significantly easier in your presentation layer and given the savings in complexity probably faster too.  As to how you do that, it would depend entirely on what your presentation layer is and how your data is made available to it.  For that, I would suggest having a go and asking new questions should you get stuck.